# Scraping first two columns of web tables with xml2

Tags: r, xml2

I have always struggled to use the xml package in R and I need some help scraping some well-formatted tables with xml2.

The url for the first page of tables I'd like to scrape is 
[here](http://www.chemicalsubstanceschimiques.gc.ca/challenge-defi/batch-lot-1/index-eng.php#s1).
On some pages I want the second and third tables, but on others I want the first and second.  A common thread is that i want all the tables where 'caption' tag includes the text 'that meet' scraped and stored in one list, and the tables where a 'caption' tag inclues the text 'that do not meet any'. But i really don't know how to get at that. The code I am working with is as follows. I can imagine that there must be some sort way to  make a regexp a condition to select the whole table.  Hope the code works.

```
#Define urls
urls<-lapply(seq(1,12, 1), function(x) paste('http://www.chemicalsubstanceschimiques.gc.ca/challenge-defi/batch-lot-',x,'/index-eng.php', sep=''))
#scrap the text
batches<-lapply(urls, function(x) read_html(x))
#Return the tables from each 
batches_tables<-lapply(batches, function(x) xml_find_all(x, './/table'))
#get the table from the first
out<-batches[[1]]
#Inspect
out[[1]] #do not want this table
out[[2]] #want this table pasted in one list, caption='that meet'
out[[2]] #want this table pasted in a second list, caption='that do not meet'
```

Comment: `rvest` has a really nice SelectorGadget which can help you find the relevant CSS or XPath selectors. See `vignette("selectorgadget", package = 'rvest')`. `rvest::html_table` would also be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Target the `caption` tag using `contains()` then move up to the parent:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.chemicalsubstanceschimiques.gc.ca/challenge-defi/batch-lot-1/index-eng.php#s1"
pg <- read_html(URL)

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//table/caption[contains(., 'that meet')]/..")
## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <table class="fontSize80">&#13;\n          <caption>&#13;\n          ...

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//table/caption[contains(., 'that do not meet')]/..")
## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <table class="fontSize85">&#13;\n          <caption>&#13;\n          ...
```